# Positional parameters question

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have this little script here:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {"$@"}
do

echo "fping -g $@"
done
```

`fping` command in used for scanning purposes.
I want to feed it with multiple arguments but when I execute the script it passes all positional parameters at the same time.

```
fping -g 1 2 3 4
fping -g 1 2 3 4
fping -g 1 2 3 4
fping -g 1 2 3 4
```

My goal is to have it like this :

```
fping -g 1
fping -g 2
fping -g 3
fping -g 4
```

Could you help?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the "**i**" variable to achieve what you want.

```
for i in "$@"
do
        echo "fping -g $i"
done
```